# Calculate exact age from birthdate (with 1/2)

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to determine a users exact age, calculated off their birthdate.

I need to be able to tell if they are 1/2 through their current year or not.

*Example:*

- 08/17/1983 -> 29 1/2
- 05/21/1983 -> 30

Here's what I currently use for the age calculation function:

```
$birthday = new DateTime($birthday);
$interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
$age = $interval->y;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could just test the m part of the interval.

```
if ($interval->m >= 6 ) {
    // it's $age + 1/2
}
```

Comment: `$interval->m` doesn't work, it is not the total number of months. `y*12 + m` is.

Comment: Good to know, but I can still tell if I should add .5 just by testing if it's >= 6, no?

Comment: Good point. I still prefer to calculate the full value directly, instead of doing two separate calculations.

Comment: Ya, I didn't read this as "I want to get 29.5", I read it as "I want 29 and I want to know if I should add the string "1/2"".

Comment: Could be the case, +1 for the simplicity of your solution.

Comment: Right back at ya, since I wouldn't have known the limits of ->m without your comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the exact months in your interval, then divide by 6, truncate, then divide by 2.

`/6 + truncate + /2` is like `/12` with .0 or .5 only .

```
<?php 

$birthday = new DateTime('08/17/1983');
$interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
$age = floor((($interval->y * 12) + $interval->m) / 6) / 2;

//To display with floating point
echo $age;

echo '<br />';

//To display with "1/2"
echo floor($age) . (fmod($age, 1) == 0.5 ? ' 1/2' : '');

?>
```

Result: `29.5` and `29 1/2`

Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m7c-uck